# Chart.js usage error (v2.4)

Tags: chart.js

I'm now working on chart.js(V2.4) and I have some problems.

I've looked up a lot of similar issues/questions but none of it solves my problem.

Error in console log shows: "Chart.controllers[meta.type] is not a constructor"

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <label style="margin-left:3%;">X : </label>
      <select id="selectxfield" style="width:20%;margin-top:2%;margin-left:1%;display:inline;">
        <option>player</option>
      </select>
      <label style="margin-left:3%;">Y : </label>
      <select name="selectyfield" style="width:20%;margin-left:1%;display:inline;">
        <option>ppg</option>
      </select>
    <button id="btnchart" style="margin-left:3%;">Submit</button>
    <canvas id="areaChart" style="height:250px"></canvas>
    <canvas id="lineChart" style="height:250px"></canvas>
    <canvas id="barChart" style="height:250px"></canvas>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    // This will get the first returned node in the jQuery collection.
    function isEmpty(obj){
        for(var key in obj){
            if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    function randomColor() {
        var colorVal = "rgb(";
        for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            colorVal += Math.round(250*Math.random());
            if (i < 2) {
                colorVal += ",";
            }
        }
        colorVal += ")";
        return colorVal;
    }

    $('#btnchart').click(function(){
        var jsdata = '{"name": "2011NBA.csv", "resource_id": "pao3ckw7b3lj8eh4ad0899oiy", "success": "true", "records": [{"id": 1, "player": "LeBron James", "division": "East", "ppg": "27.1", "rpg": "7.9", "apg": "6.2", "blk": "0.81", "stl": "1.85"}, {"id": 2, "player": "Kevin Durant", "division": "West", "ppg": "28", "rpg": "8", "apg": "3.5", "blk": "1.17", "stl": "1.33"}, {"id": 3, "player": "Dwight Howard", "division": "East", "ppg": "20.6", "rpg": "14.5", "apg": "1.9", "blk": "2.15", "stl": "1.5"}, {"id": 4, "player": "Christ Paul", "division": "West", "ppg": "19.8", "rpg": "3.6", "apg": "9.1", "blk": "0.07", "stl": "2.53"}, {"id": 5, "player": "Derrick Rose", "division": "East", "ppg": "21.8", "rpg": "3.4", "apg": "7.9", "blk": "0.72", "stl": "0.9"}]}'
        var data = JSON.parse(jsdata);
        var x = []; // use array to save the field's name
        var y = []; // use array to save data
        var xf = $( "#selectxfield option:selected" ).text();// get selected value
        $.each(data.records, function(i, v) {
            x.push(v[xf]);
        });
        var areaChartData = {
            labels: x,
            datasets: []
        };

        var selectyfield = document.getElementsByName('selectyfield') // selectyfield can be added dynamically in my code, but I set it to one just for debug convenience
        var dt = data.records;
        for (j=0;j<selectyfield.length;j++){
            var color = randomColor();
            var index = selectyfield[j].selectedIndex;
            var k = selectyfield[j].options[index].text;

            $.each(data.records, function(ky, vl) {
                y.push(parseFloat(vl[k]));
            });
            if (isEmpty(data.records)){
                $.each(dt, function(ky, vl) {
                    y.push(parseFloat(vl[k]));
                });
            }
            var data ={
                label: k,
                fillColor: color,
                strokeColor: color,
                pointColor: color,
                pointStrokeColor: "#c1c7d1",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data: y
            }
            areaChartData["datasets"].push(data);
            y = [];
        }
        var areaChartOptions = {
            // a lot of options
        };
        var barChartOptions = {
            // a lot of options
        };
        var area = document.getElementById("areaChart")
        var areaChartCanvas = area.getContext("2d");
        var areaChart = new Chart(areaChartCanvas,{
            type: "area",
            data: areaChartData,
            options: areaChartOptions
        });

        var line = document.getElementById("lineChart")
        var lineChartCanvas = line.getContext("2d");
        var lineChartOptions = areaChartOptions;
        var lineChartData = areaChartData;
        lineChartOptions.datasetFill = false;
        var lineChart = new Chart(lineChartCanvas,{
            type: "line",
            data: lineChartData,
            options: lineChartOptions
        });

        var bar = document.getElementById("barChart")
        var barChartCanvas = bar.getContext("2d");
        var barChartData = areaChartData;
        barChartOptions.datasetFill = false;
        var lineChart = new Chart(barChartCanvas,{
            type: "bar",
            data: barChartData,
            options: barChartOptions
        });
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

The select field is fixed just for convenience.

I am sure the code works fine in older chart.js (v1.X), I just have to change some code usage above.

Hope someone can help me finding the error, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few days later, I finally reached the contributors and members of chart.js.

They helped me and pointed out that there's no chart type named "area".

After deleting that part, the code works fine.

It's still strange that the debug message didn't show relative information but something not correlated to.

Answer (score 0):

I just hit a similar problem. Looking into the source, it seems `Chart.controllers` is an object with all the different types of chart as properties. `meta.type` is whatever you pass as `type` in the options hash to the `new Chart()` constructor. So in your case it was complaining that `Chart.controllers["area"]` is not a constructor.

I appreciate that you've already found the answer to your specific problem, but I thought it would be worth expanding on this because (a) as you pointed out, the debug message is a bit unhelpful by itself, and (b) this might help anyone who has similar difficulties (for example, in my case I put in "Line" instead of "line" and if I'd understood what the error message actually meant it would have saved me a bit of digging).